# Is the Taproot script tree commitment quantum safe?

Tags: script, taproot, quantum-computing

If an attacker in posession of a quantum computer can break the ECDLP, they can of course spend every Taproot output using the key path. However, do they also have the ability to construct a valid control block and spend using the script path with a script of their own choosing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered by Pieter Wuille on [Delving Bitcoin](https://delvingbitcoin.org/t/lamport-signatures-and-other-cat-tricks/236/6):

> As long as SHA256 remains preimage resistant, script path spends
> remain secure (obviously only under the assumption the script itself
> isn’t vulnerable to a DL break).